# Перезагрузка vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Регулярно сталкиваюсь с проблемой. После выкатки, пользователи не могут пользоваться системой из-за того, что поменялось что-нибудь в store. Всё валится в техподдержку. А нужно всего лишь очистить стор, куки и кэш. Как обойти эту проблему?

Comment: Причем тут vuex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`location.reload(true);`

Данная команда должна гасить кэш и стор